# Unlocking max power on i7 12800H

Tags: power-management, intel, performance, cpu

I have an i7 12800H processor that should be boosting to over 100W of power, but it never goes above 45W as per `turbostat`. The fans of the computer don't even spin up.

This is what I get from `powercap-info intel-rapl`:

```
> powercap-info intel-rapl
enabled: 1
Zone 0
  name: package-0
  enabled: 1
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 65000000
    time_window_us: 55967744
    max_power_uw: 45000000
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 160000000
    time_window_us: 2440
    max_power_uw: 0
  Constraint 2
    name: peak_power
    power_limit_uw: 236000000
    time_window_us: 0
    max_power_uw: 0
  Zone 0:0
    name: core
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
  Zone 0:1
    name: uncore
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
Zone 1
  name: psys
  enabled: 0
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 27983872
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 976
```

The power limits look OK, those are the correct values (65W and 160W).

The problem seems to be on the `max_power_uw: 45000000` line of the constraint 0. I can't change that one, and seems to be limiting the power regardless of the power limits.

I've seen a lot of posts about changing the power limits, but in my case those are correct. I don't see anything about that `max_power_uw`.

What can I check?

## Update

I have another laptop with an i7-1165G7 where PL1 is 35W but `max_power_uw` is 28W, and this one does boost to 35W without problem, so `max_power_uw` is not what is stopping the 12800H from boosting, it has to be something else. Here is the powercap-info output:

```
powercap-info intel-rapl
enabled: 1
Zone 0
  name: package-0
  enabled: 1
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 35000000
    time_window_us: 27983872
    max_power_uw: 28000000
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 65000000
    time_window_us: 2440
    max_power_uw: 0
  Constraint 2
    name: peak_power
    power_limit_uw: 121000000
    time_window_us: 0
    max_power_uw: 0
  Zone 0:0
    name: core
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
  Zone 0:1
    name: uncore
    enabled: 0
    max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
    Constraint 0
      name: long_term
      power_limit_uw: 0
      time_window_us: 976
Zone 1
  name: psys
  enabled: 0
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  Constraint 0
    name: long_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 27983872
  Constraint 1
    name: short_term
    power_limit_uw: 0
    time_window_us: 976
```

Comment: 45 watts looks right to me. See [here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/226059/intel-core-i7-12800h-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz.html).

Comment: @DougSmythies on this latptop I think it should be 65, but right or wrong, it should boost above that and it is not boosting.

Comment: The boost window time is really short, so it might be difficult to see with turbostat. Try and interval of 0.001 seconds, where the burst load of 160 watts might appear as 73 watts (2440*160+7560*45 (the formula isn't actually that simple)). Note: turbostat itself will use significant power at that rate. Could you edit your question adding the turbostat startup spew of information when the `--quiet` option is not used. I am used to looking at power limits that way verses powercap-info.

Comment: @DougSmythies Sustained power should be at 65W anyway, and it is peacking at 45.

Comment: I think your processor is "locked", so there isn't anything you can do. See if you can extract anything useful from [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231091/tee-constraint-0-power-limit-uw-no-data-available)

Comment: Everything is about the "power limits". In my case they are correct. An I can change them. The problem seems to be "max power" or perhaps on another subsystem. Anyway, the CPU should boost over 45W, this is a laptop with lots of cooling that is supposed to boost over 100W. I haven't checked on Windows but I'm pretty sure it won't start throtling inmediately while the CPU is cool.